# Typing in safari all of a sudden moves to a new textbox

Tags: safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this bar appearing in Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22468/why-is-this-bar-appearing-in-safari)

Sometimes when I'm typing in (Japanese) a text box in the safari browser, all of a sudden a new thin text window appears in the bottom left corner and my typed text is transfered there. This box has no title or anything, just a minimize icon.

After that I can't type anywhere else. I have to close this text box and the tab I was working on. Only after I open a new tab does this problem to go away. What the heck is going on and how do I stop it?

You can see why I've had trouble googling this >_<

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Does it happen on specific sites only or on all sites? Are there any plugins installed? If yes, does the problem persist after you disable all of them?

Comment: Does it look anything like the problem here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22468/why-is-this-bar-appearing-in-safari ?

Comment: Thanks @Mahnax that is totally the problem. I was looking for that on app stack exchange. I still have no idea how to stop it though.

Comment: @Slamice Does it happen whilst typing in English?

Comment: This can be closed as duplicate I guess.

Comment: No it's in Japanese I forgot to add that.